# Como enviar datos de un radio en especifico a través de ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax, radiobutton

de antemano gracias se que quizás la pregunta no se entendió completamente les explico.

yo tengo un div con mi formulario donde hay varios select y varios radios con el mismo id y el mismo nombre para que solo se seleccione 1 el problema esta que estoy enviando este formulario a travez e ajax y no con el metodo basico, el error llega cuando hago el envio de los datos con el atributo ID="" pero al tener varios  solo escoje el primero y creo que ni cambiandolo a clases causaria un efecto que no sea tomar el valor del primer elemento con ese identificador aqui les dejo parte del codigo gracias.

ajax:

```
    function dispenviar(sender){
        var especialidad=$('#especialidad').val();
        var tanda=$('#tanda').val();
        var fecha=$('#fecha').val();
        var idpaciente=$('#idd').val();
        var idmedico=$('#medico').val();

            $.ajax({
                url : "funciones/insertar/prog_consulta.php",
                data : {especialidad:especialidad, tanda:tanda, fecha:fecha, idpaciente:idpaciente,
                        idmedico:idmedico},
                type : "POST",
                success : function(datos){
                    $("#notify").html(datos);
                }
            });
    }
```

HTML ejemplo sin el php.

```
<label>
```

[2] starking elyos smith

Repito lo que quiero es cuando seleciono estos radios me tome el valor del propio y no del primer ID. lo que no entiendo es como usar el metodo this por que yo tengo un boton para ejecutar el ajax y no el mismo radio.

Comment: podrias usar un for para recorrer los input radio y preguntar cual tiene el estado checked

Answer (score 0):

Por de pronto te diría que el identificador debe ser único. Si quieres tener un grupo de radiobuttons para que sean excluyentes utiliza el atributo `name`.

Aquí más info: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio

Por otro lado, suponiendo que especialidad sea el identificador de tus radiobuttons, al hacer un `especialidad=$('#especialidad').val();` va a seleccionar todos los elementos con `id` = "especialidad" (todos) y al hacer el `.val()` obtendrá el primero de ellos.

Lo que deberías hacer es poner distinto `id` a los radiobuttons, agrupándolos por el mismo `name` y luego seleccionar el `radio` seleccionado así:

```
$("input:radio[name=nombreGrupo]").click(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
});
```

Te dejo este fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o7ay78ce/3/